# Laravel Eloquent use "where" and "orWhereHas" together

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get Orders using where and where has for belongsToMany relationship.

The where query works but where has is not being executed.

```
$orders = Order::where('contact_email', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('Products',function( $query ) use ( $term ){
            $query->where('model', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->simplePaginate(25)
        ->appends(request()->query());
```

From Order.php

```
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','order_product')->has('transfer', '<', 1)->whereHas('order', function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'order');
            $query->where('id','<>',$this->id);
        }, '<', 1)->withPivot('price');
    }
```

Products Table Migration file...

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable(); 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategory_id')->nullable(); 
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('manufacturer_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('condition_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('model')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('cost', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('dealer_price', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('serial')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('featured');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->longText('service_notes')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: how do you know it isn't "executed"?

Comment: the column 'model' in the products table is it containing emails?

Comment: I think it is not executed because it does not return results that i do get when i use whereHas by itself

Comment: Yes the orders table has "contact_email" the products table is a relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put orWhereHas under orWhere level.

```
$orders = Order::where('contact_email', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->orWhere(function ($orWhere) use ($term) {
        $orWhere->orWhereHas('Products',function($products) use ($term) {
            $products->where('model', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        })
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->simplePaginate(25)
    ->appends(request()->query());
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe something wrong with the relationship? This still does not return any products where model like $term

Comment: Can you post related tables description?

Comment: Added Order model and products table info above

Comment: Apologies this solution does work, there was a global scope interfering with the query.